# What will happen when sending raw bytes via SMS?

Tags: sms, twilio

We would like to send 140 raw binary bytes (8-bit) between our cloud server and our hardware device (and vice-versa) via a SMS payload. We do not intend to send traditional text ("normal" SMS) as the data will not need to be human-readable. As the bytes are raw, there would be no encoding (i.e. would not be GSM 7-bit). Is that possible? If so, what will be delivered to the client at the other end?

In particular, does Twilio or carriers (Verizon, AT&T, etc.) support this in their APIs? It doesn't seem like it so we are worried that if we just send raw bytes as the message body the SMS transport layer will change it to standard GSM 7-bit, which we do not want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Twilio's APIs but you can send SMS messages two ways: text mode and PDU mode. PDU mode is for sending binary data. This is how images and monophonic ring-tones were sent a decade ago. It's also how you send a WAP Push message to effect MMS. You'll want to send your data PDU mode. You can even concatenate messages if you want to send more than 140 8bit bytes.

Here's a link that show's the PDU format:

[SMS PDU mode](http://www.gsm-modem.de/sms-pdu-mode.html)

Comment: Right, I've seen that flag for PDU mode. The problem I've seen is that the telco carriers (and Twilio, too) don't seem to expose that option in their APIs. I've asked this question directly of Twilio to see what they say, too.

Comment: All network operators will support PDU mode on their SMSC.  This is how they send MMS messages. If you aren't using SMPP directly it will depend on the messaging gateway vendor. Look for their MMS apis. I know OpenMarket supports it. Looks like Twilio doesn't anymore, but I may be wrong.